# openCV cvSaveImage and cvCvtColor crash on android

Tags: android, opencv, javacv

I'm working on android with version 2.3.5 and 4.0.4 both version crash on the execution of the same code.
I have been trying to get a frame from a video, save it, and then convert it to HSV.

(I posted this same question on the opencv website [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/18389/opencv-cvsaveimage-and-cvcvtcolor-crash-on-android/))

This is my code and the error I get.

```
  public void process(){
        IplImage orgImg = this.getFrame(2);
                cvSaveImage(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/openCV/orgimg.jpg", orgImg);
                IplImage hsv = hsv(orgImg);
    }

    private IplImage getFrame(int id){
            File testfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + videoFile);

            if(testfile.canRead()){ 

                FFmpegFrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(testfile);  
                try {
                    grabber.start();
                    grabber.setFrameNumber(id);
                    final int height=grabber.getImageHeight();
                    final int width=grabber.getImageWidth();
                    IplImage frame = IplImage.create(width, height, 8, 4);
                    frame = grabber.grab();
                    //grabber.stop();
                    return frame;
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

private IplImage hsv(IplImage orgImg) {
        // 8-bit, 3- color =(RGB)
        IplImage imgHSV = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(orgImg), 8, 3);
        Log.e(TAG,"hsvThreshold - Image size" + cvGetSize(orgImg));
        cvCvtColor(orgImg, imgHSV, CV_BGR2HSV);

        return imgHSV;
    }
```

Here is the logcat I get when cvSaveImage or cvCvtColor is executed on the device running 4.0.4

```
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719): "main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40bf1460 self=0x101aca8
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   | sysTid=6719 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1074673032
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   | schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=710 stm=34 core=0
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:368)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:217)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at ch.golfer.TrackSpot.process(TrackSpot.java:-1)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at ch.golfer.FullscreenActivity$7.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:196)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3627)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14305)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:976)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
08-07 12:26:25.974: I/dalvikvm(6719):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 12:26:25.974: E/dalvikvm(6719): VM aborting
08-07 12:26:25.974: A/libc(6719): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)
```

And this is the logcat of the 2.3.5 device:

```
08-07 12:32:05.503: E/javacpp(995): Error loading class com/googlecode/javacpp/Pointer.
08-07 12:32:09.620: I/dalvikvm(995): threadid=4: reacting to signal 3
08-07 12:32:10.620: W/dalvikvm(995): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-07 12:32:11.370: W/dalvikvm(995): threadid=4: spin on suspend #2 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050e148 self=0x288d08
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=999 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2078152
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f190 self=0xce60
08-07 12:32:11.370: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=995 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
08-07 12:32:11.456: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:11.472: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:11.476: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:432)
08-07 12:32:11.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-07 12:32:11.507: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
08-07 12:32:11.511: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
08-07 12:32:11.519: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
08-07 12:32:11.527: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
08-07 12:32:11.530: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:11.534: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
08-07 12:32:11.542: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
08-07 12:32:11.550: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
08-07 12:32:11.554: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.TrackSpot.process(TrackSpot.java:-1)
08-07 12:32:11.562: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.FullscreenActivity$7.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:196)
08-07 12:32:11.570: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
08-07 12:32:11.581: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
08-07 12:32:11.589: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-07 12:32:11.593: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 12:32:11.605: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-07 12:32:11.616: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
08-07 12:32:11.620: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:11.624: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-07 12:32:11.632: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-07 12:32:11.640: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-07 12:32:11.648: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:12.405: W/dalvikvm(995): threadid=4: spin on suspend #3 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050e148 self=0x288d08
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=999 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2078152
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f190 self=0xce60
08-07 12:32:12.405: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=995 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
08-07 12:32:12.460: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:12.472: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:12.480: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:432)
08-07 12:32:12.484: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.TrackSpot.process(TrackSpot.java:-1)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.FullscreenActivity$7.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:196)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-07 12:32:12.488: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:13.241: W/dalvikvm(995): threadid=4: spin on suspend #4 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050e148 self=0x288d08
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=999 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2078152
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f190 self=0xce60
08-07 12:32:13.241: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=995 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
08-07 12:32:13.280: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:432)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
08-07 12:32:13.292: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.TrackSpot.process(TrackSpot.java:-1)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.FullscreenActivity$7.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:196)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-07 12:32:13.296: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:14.046: W/dalvikvm(995): threadid=4: spin on suspend #5 threadid=1 (pcf=0)
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4050e148 self=0x288d08
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=999 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2078152
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4001f190 self=0xce60
08-07 12:32:14.050: I/dalvikvm(995):   | sysTid=995 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1345006496
08-07 12:32:14.062: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:14.062: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:14.062: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:432)
08-07 12:32:14.066: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
08-07 12:32:14.070: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
08-07 12:32:14.073: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
08-07 12:32:14.073: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_imgproc.<clinit>(opencv_imgproc.java:97)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:453)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_highgui.<clinit>(opencv_highgui.java:85)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.TrackSpot.process(TrackSpot.java:-1)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at ch.golfer.FullscreenActivity$7.onClick(FullscreenActivity.java:196)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3688)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-07 12:32:14.077: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
08-07 12:32:14.085: I/dalvikvm(995):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
08-07 12:32:14.085: I/dalvikvm(995):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, this is my theory:

This code is running through JNI; therefore, when I grab the image and set it equal to another image, it just passes the pointer. Additionally, because I start my grabber in the getFrame function, the grabber gets destroyed when the image is returned, and for a weird reason the memory gets flushed and the passed pointer becomes useless.

The solution to the issue is to either set the grabber as a global variable, to pass the grabber as an argument to the getFrame function, or (weirdly) to execute an opencv operation that touches the memory before returning the image (i.e. call cvCvSaveimage or cvCvtColor on something random does not even have to be related to the image).

I hope my explanation makes sense, and I do not know if it should be reported as a bug though ?